# How to assign keys and save it as dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary-comprehension

I am new to python. I was working with a CSV file which looks something like:

```
man,nut,bag
rat,cat
dog,fog,cat,man
```

Thing is, I want to assign a unique number to each of these values in the csv file such that the unique number acts as the key and the item in the CSV acts as the value like in a dictionary.
Also if any value gets repeated in the CSV file, I don't want to assign another key to it.

The desired output should be something like this:

```
dictionary=
{
1: "man",
2: "nut",
.
.
.
6: "dog",
7: "fog",
5: "cat",
1: "man"
}
```

Comment: A python dict can have unique keys only (man cannot be repeated), but the values can be repeated.

Comment: Maybe your value should be the key and your key should be the value?

Comment: @klaus Oh Yes, sorry! I typed it wrong!

Comment: @Praveenkumar Yes, Sorry I typed it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would probably do something like this (you would have to reoplace the `StringIO(txt)` part with `open('file.csv', 'r')`):

```
from io import StringIO
from csv import reader

txt = """man,nut,bag
rat,cat
dog,fog,cat,man"""

dct = {}

with StringIO(txt) as file:
    rows = reader(file)
    for row in rows:
        for word in row:
            if word not in dct:
                dct[word] = len(dct)
# {'man': 0, 'nut': 1, 'bag': 2, 'rat': 3, 'cat': 4, 'dog': 5, 'fog': 6}
```

and if you want to avoid the `csv` import at all costs (why?!) you could just split every line of your file:

```
with StringIO(txt) as file:
    for line in file:
        row = line.strip().split(",")
        for word in row:
            if word not in dct:
                dct[word] = len(dct)
```

Comment: Thank You! CSV can be used, I was specifically referring against the use of Pandas, etc libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a dictionary to save the value of each word in the csv file and then use a list to save the repeated pairs of (value, word)

Example:

```
value_of_word_dict = {}
for word in csv:
    value_of_word_dict[word] = # assign value to the word

value_of_word_dict = {'man':1, 'nut':2, 'bag':3, 'rat':4, 'cat':5, 'dog':6, 'fog':7}

output = []
for word in csv:
    word_value = value_of_word_dict[word]
    output.append((word_value, word))
output = [
(1, "man")
(2, "nut"),
(3, "bag"),
(4, "rat"),
(5, "cat"),
(6, "dog"),
(7, "fog"),
(5, "cat"),
(1, "man")
]
```

The variable `output` is what you want. It will not be a dictionary, but a list, as dictionaries don't allow repeating keys.

Answer (score 0):

Hello & sorry ( can't comment yet )

First of all:
A dict is named indexed by a string.
Therefore your "dictionary" example is impossible.

A list or tuple owning a "natural" number indexing.
The only thing to do is avoiding doubles (man,cat).
Then you easily use:
`first_value = name_of_list_or_tuple[0]`
...for the very first (starts with 0) value.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph. Can you expand it with more details?

Comment: Example:`for number in range(0,len(dir())): dir()[number]` shows all list values from 0 to len(dir())